# how to turn off Tableau automatic updates for filters

Tags: tableau-api

In [Tableau FAQ instruction](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/queries_autoupdates.htm#:%7E:text=To%20pause%20automatic%20updates%20for%20filters%2C%20click%20the%20drop-down,to%20clear%20the%20check%20mark%20.) is next:

> To pause automatic updates for filters, click the drop-down arrow on the Pause Auto Updates button on the toolbar and select Auto Update Filters to clear the check mark .

> To resume automatic updates for filters, click the drop-down arrow on the Pause Auto Updates button on the toolbar and select Auto Update Filters again. You can also click the Run Update  button on the toolbar to manually update the view at any time.

Problem is that in our workbook doesn't appear drop-down arrow on the Pause Auto Updates. How to turn off auto-updates for filters?

Screen Cast: https://d.pr/v/sZ6sek

Comment: The FAQ is for tableau desktop (not server as your image suggests). For tableau desktop the options are available, see [ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uegv.png)

Answer (score -1):

The dropdown comes in the new version of Tableau.

You can refer to the below image:

[image]